# How do you know if a post has an accepted answer by just looking at the list of questions?

Tags: support, accepted-answer, question-lists

I have just started following the new questions related to tags of my interest.I go to Tags click on Java for instance and the page shows me the list of most recent java related questions in the forum.

**Just by looking at the list of questions you cannot make out if a post has an answer that already has been accepted. (Unless there is something else that I am missing)**

It would be a great to know if a post has an accepted answer , both for folks who want to answer a question and for those who are looking for an answer.

Answer (score 7):

If the number of answer is yellow, there is an accepted answer.  If it's white, there's not.

[image]

Comment: Could it be an actual problem that a notable percentage of males is color blinded?

Comment: I guess I am color blind then or one with poor observation skill

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My understanding of the most common types of color blindness is that the colors in question aren't particularly likely to be indistinguishable.

Comment: @Servy (_@Will_) Uhhh, red / green makes this even worse regarding my concerns ;-). Though, it wasn't really meant as a joke. It's hard to distinguish, unless you have the experience.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The problem isn't that someone can't distinguish between the two when they're looking for it, it's that people don't know to look for it.

Comment: I'm a little CB, i can BARELY tell the difference.

Comment: @briansol Monitor and OS graphics settings can matter too.

Comment: all of which are locked down by IT/hardware team here at the office

Comment: Seriously, it's one thing for people who are CB.... but for others, "not knowing what to look for".... this is a site for coders. Technically, coders see this kind of thing. I realized it because I saw some answers in yellow, some in white, then I tried to realize the associated behavior... that's how I found out. not hard honestly, just needs a tad of curiosity and judgement

Comment: Regardless of whether the inability to discern the *accepted* status of a question is observational or insufficient photopigments, I don't think I'd like to be a passenger in a car with at least half of the responders here at the wheel.

Comment: @Servy: Could you please update this answer with the new colors?

Comment: @Cerbrus: You can also just downvote this one and upvote the newer answer. Since it's Meta, it votes doesn't really matter except for answer order.

Answer (score 3):

A more visually distinct design is now in effect which may help users who find it difficult to identify slight difference in colors. Now posts having an accepted answer have a green background behind the answer count whereas a transparent background for post that dont have an accepted answer.

> [image]